# .htaccess redirect of subfolder to other domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I recently moved to another server, but one iframe temporally needs to be server from the old one. I need to redirect

http://example.com/iframe/*

to

http://123.456.789.012/iframe/*

In example.com/iframe/.htacces I attempted

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /iframe/(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://123.456.789.012/$1 [L,R=302]
```

and

```
RewriteRule iframe/(.*)$  http://123.456.789.012/iframe/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

(among others), all failed.

EDIT:

1. The .htaccess is definitly parsed. Garbage in the file renders HTTP 500
2. When I create a simple text file on the new server, I can open it - so at least the URL points to where it belongs

What did I miss? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this rule in `example.com/iframe/.htacces`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=123.456.789.012
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://123.456.789.012/iframe/$1 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Test it after completely clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, I get all 404s. Could you hint me how to debug such cases? Thanks so much!

Comment: I did. (Sorry, that's what I meant with that cryptical "The .htaccess is definitly parsed.")

Comment: Gosh, I just realized that I missed to copy the RewriteEngine directive. Really long day today. Thanks again, answer accepted. (Seems hard to miss 1 out of just 3 lines, I know... :) )